# Introductory text for primatology

Tags: ecology, ethology, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a book that provides a good overview of primatology, one aimed more at researchers rather than a popular science book. Ideally, I'd like something with an ethology/ecology angle with an eye towards phylogeny.

My preference would be for an e-book.

Comment: Lucas, I put more of a professional spin on this so it's not as much of a "shopping"-type question.

Comment: @jonsca I appreciate your effort, but you did change the nature of my question. I definitely want a good book, that is very important, it really does not matter if it is a canonical text or not. The ability to soundly judge things good or bad is the true value of professionalism ;)

Comment: well, maybe of expertise, but that didn't fit :)

Comment: Your changes to it are fine, thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

I've had some experience with Karen Strier's 'Primate Behavioural Ecology', and it's solid. It's a nice overview with (obviously) a strong ecology/ethology bent. I don't think it comes in ebook though.

Here's the [Amazon link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0205790178).

Comment: Sweet Jesus that's expensive. Not unusually so, but I'd managed to forget how much academic books are.